# Memory Regions displayed in SMAPS output with no permissions

Tags: linux-kernel

If I see the output of cat /proc//smaps, I find that there are some memory regions with which no read/write/execute permissions have been associated. Also these region are mapped to inode number 0.

I wanted to know how does a region end up in such a state? Is it some sort of memory leak?

Can these regions be ever used again by the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not leaks.  They're created by calling `mmap()` with the `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `PROT_NONE` flags.  The process can still use that virtual address space: it could unmap the regions with `munmap()`, or alter the protections with `mprotect()`.

Such regions are typically used to set up *guard pages*, which are intended to trigger a signal when a growing data structure grows beyond its current bound.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more thing, can you point some source(book/ebook/website) where I can learn such specific things? My primary motto is not to bug you again and again and learn by myself.